# CSS speech bubble with rounded arrow

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'm trying to recreate the following image in CSS:

[image]

I've already started making the box and arrow (see below) and now my only problem is to make the left edge of the arrow round with CSS only just like in the image.
Any idea? Thanks.

```css
.speech-bubble {
    position: relative;
    background: #ff0d1e;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 239px;
    height: 95px;
    margin: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.speech-bubble:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: -32px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 0 32px 20px 0;
    border-color: transparent #ff0d1e transparent transparent;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="speech-bubble"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this using `transform: skew();` and `border-radius`. I added `z-index: -1` to the pseudo-element so it sits behind the `<span>` (I'm assuming you will put text inside).

```css
.speech-bubble {
    position: relative;
    background: #ff0d1e;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 239px;
    height: 95px;
    margin: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.speech-bubble:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: -32px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #ff0d1e;
    transform: skew(55deg);
    transform-origin: top right;
    border-radius: 15% 0 0 0 / 25%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<span class="speech-bubble"></span>
```

Comment: Just brilliant!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

It's still slightly pointed, but if you used corner-specific border-radius properties you can get a similar effect.

Here I used `border-top-left-radius` and `border-bottom-left-radius`.

```css
.speech-bubble {
    position: relative;
    background: #ff0d1e;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 239px;
    height: 95px;
    margin: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.speech-bubble:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: -32px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 0 32px 20px 0;
    border-color: transparent #ff0d1e transparent transparent;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    border-top-left-radius:80%;
    border-bottom-left-radius:200%;
}
```

```html
<span class="speech-bubble"></span>
```